# Xamarin.Forms Behaviors

Tags: xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms seems to be offering an alternative approach called "behaviors" to subclassing controls. Why was this ever required in the first place? What is the advantage and when should we use it instead of subclassing?

One possible reason I am thimking might be that subclassed controls cannot use the styles targeted for their parent controls. But I don't understand the reason of that restriction either.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Xamaron.Forms Behavior documentation, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/behaviors/

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** *I am not exactly sure, I understand what you mean here.*

> One possible reason I am thinking might be that subclassed controls cannot use the styles targeted for their parent controls. But I don't understand the reason of that restriction either.

*But, I will try to provide an answer to questions mentioned in this paragraph.*

> Xamarin.Forms seems to be offering an alternative approach called "behaviors" to subclassing controls. Why was this ever required in the first place? What is the advantage and when should we use it instead of subclassing?

---

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/introduction/), behaviors allow you to extend functionalities for controls without having to derive them. I guess it would make more sense to implement a behavior, rather then subclass a control, in following cases:

- **If functionality can be shared across multiple control types**

  Simplest example would be implementing max-length/regex/min-length validation for controls that support input such as `Entry`, `Editor` etc.

  ```
    <Entry>
      <Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:TextBehaviour MaxLength="25" MinLength="2" RegexPattern="[ae]" />
      </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>

    <Editor>
      <Editor.Behaviors>
        <local:TextBehaviour MaxLength="250" MinLength="2" />
      </Editor.Behaviors>
    </Editor>
  ```
- **If functionality needs to be extended for controls used in an existing code-base**

  For example, we can extend, and attach behaviors to various controls using implicit styles and attached properties without having to update each control usage in code.

  ```
  <Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="local:ShadowEffect.HasShadow" Value="True" />
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="local:Validation.MaxLength" Value="35" />
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="Editor">
    <Setter Property="local:Validation.MaxLength" Value="250" />
  </Style>
  ```

These are the scenarios I can think of at this point. I will add more, if I come across any more.

Answer (score 0):

It's a concept coming from WPF, you can read more about it on [this great tutorial page](https://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html).

> The ideas behind behaviors are to give the interaction designer more flexibility to design complex user interactions without writing any code.
>
> Example of a behaviors are drag&drop, input validation, pan and zoom,
>   re-position of elements, etc... The list of possible behaviors is very
>   long.
>
> Imaging an application that has a list of customers and the user can
>   add some of them to subscriber lists. This interaction can be designed
>   by providing an "Add" button next to each subscriber list. But if the
>   interaction designer wants to add drag&drop functionality, he needs to
>   discuss it with the developer and wait until the implementation is
>   done. With behaviors he just drags a drag and drop behavior on each
>   list and we are done.

So in a company, it allows a better workflow between designers and developers.

Another reason, in addition to the already mentioned, could be the possibility of switching behaviours during runtime.